# Understanding Node assignments in Linked List

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, variable-assignment

So I am learning Linked Lists in C currently and I have some doubts regarding some assignments used while creating a Linked List and Inserting nodes. I hope to understand how does the memory stuff works in the background.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next
}
    
void createList(int n, struct node *head)
{
    struct node *temp, *newnode;
    
    //Assignment 1
    temp = head;
    
    //Assignment2
    temp->next = newnode
    //somethings
}
```

Some Context : `head` does not contain any data. It is just the first entry point node and it points to the first node that contains any data?
`temp` is used for traversal and `newnode` is the newly created node and is changed to `temp` later.

How do the two assignments above work in terms of memory?
In Assignment 1, am I copying contents or do the two names point to same location?
Same doubts for Assignment 2.

Updated , the significant code is below.

```
int menu()
{
    int choice = 0;

    printf("\n\t\tMENU\n1.Create Linked List");
    printf("\n2.Display Linked List");
    printf("\nAny other number to exit\n");
    printf("\nEnter Choice : ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    return choice;
}

void createList(int n, struct node *head)
{
    int data;
    struct node *temp, *newNode;
    temp = head; // 'head' node with no data pointing towards 'temp'
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        printf("Enter Data %d : ", i);
        scanf("%d", &data);

        newNode->data = data; // First Node
        newNode->next = NULL;

        temp->next = newNode;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void displayList(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = head->next; // Link to First Node
    int i = 1;
    printf("\nStart Display\n");
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("\nData %d : %d\n", i, temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }
}

void main()
{
    int choice, n;

    struct node *head;
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->next = NULL;

label:
    choice = menu();
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Enter Number of Entries : ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        createList(n, head);
        goto label;
        break;

    case 2:
        displayList(head);
        goto label;
        break;

    default:
        printf("Wrong Choice");
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
}
```

Edit 2 :
Another doubt :

```
temp = temp->next
```

This is used for traversal but how does it work. 'next' is a sublocation in the 'struct node' which has address to next node right ?
So what happens with this assignment, in the memory location ?

Would appreciate the help as this topic is turning out to be very hard to understand.

Comment: The only things being copied in the two assignments are pointers. The second assignment `temp->next = newnode;` is invalid because `newnode` contains an uninitialized value.

Comment: When is assign 'temp=head' are there two distinct pointers named 'temp' or 'head' or are they both pointing to same location in memory ?

Comment: @ThomasAMathew same location.

Comment: @Imonninger . Thank You

Comment: How is `head` initialized before you pass it to `createList`?

Comment: In void main() . head is initialized and assigned space using malloc. Then the head->next points to NULL and then head is passed.

Comment: After `int a = 42; int b; b = a;` there are two distinct `int` objects named `a` and `b` and they contain the same integer value 42. It is the same for pointers, but valid pointer values contain the address of some object in memory. So after `temp=head;`, there are still two distinct pointer objects named `temp` and `head`, but they both contain the same pointer value (the pointer value that was already stored in `head`).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that it is fairly unusual to use a dummy node at the start of a (non-circular) list. Usually, the list is represented by a pointer variable that is NULL when the list is empty, or points to the first element when the list is not empty. For example, `createList` could be defined without the `head` parameter and it could return a pointer to the first element of the created list.

Comment: Well I was following a particular site and they showed this method. After learning I had a sense of not needing the node. But I am practicing with the same template.

Comment: Aside: `void main()` -> [`int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).

Comment: I haven't learned the utility of 'int main(arguments)' yet .

Comment: @ThomasAMathew Then use the first form shown: `int main(void)`, or simply ignore `argc` and `argv` for the time being. Unless you are working in a freestanding environment, which seems highly unlikely for a beginner, `void main()` is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

In the both assignments values stored in objects in the right hand side are assigned to the objects in the left  hand side.

For example if the pointer head is a null pointer then after the assignment

```
temp = head;
```

the pointer temp also will be a null pointer.

If the pointer head points to some object (node) of the type struct node (stores the address of the node) then after the assignment the pointer temp also will point to this object (node). That is it will store the same memory address of the node.

To make it more clear consider the following code snippet.

```
int x = 10;
int *p = &x;
int *q;

q = p;
```

After the assignment the both pointers p and q point to the variable x. So using either of the pointers you can access the variable x as for example

```
printf ( "x = %d\n", *q );

*q = 20;

printf ( "x = %d\n", *p );
```

As for the appended code of the function

```
void createList(int n, struct node *head)
{
    int data;
    struct node *temp, *newNode;
    temp = head; // 'head' node with no data pointing towards 'temp'
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        printf("Enter Data %d : ", i);
        scanf("%d", &data);

        newNode->data = data; // First Node
        newNode->next = NULL;

        temp->next = newNode;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Then it has undefined behavior provided that the pointer head initially does not point to a dummy node and is equal to NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Some clarification : Say if 'head' has data and next points to something else. If 'temp = head' , Is now temp pointing to location where head is pointing to. OR now is there two distinct places named 'temp' or 'head'?

Comment: @ThomasAMathew temp and head are two 'distinct place" because they are defined in different memory extents bit after the assignment they have the same value..

Comment: Thank You Vlad. A bit of clarification if you don't mind. The function 'createList',  how does it work ? The code works but when I assign 'temp=head'. Does this mean 'head' has a memory address(because its a pointer) of some location and does the assignment put the memory address inside 'head' to 'temp' ? Am I correct regarding this ? Say if 'head' is containing address : #r450(location name) and now 'temp' contains the same that is 'temp' also has value #r450 and hence both 'temp' and 'head' points to same location ?. Hope you understood .Thanks for you guidance, I am really struggling here.

Comment: @ThomasAMathew The value stored in one object is assigned to another object. After the assignment the both objects have the same value. What is unclear?

Comment: Hi Vlad, when I declare 'temp' and 'head' they are pointer variables right ? If 'head' is pointing to some memory location and if I do 'temp=head', the two variables are still two distinct places in the memory right ? They are not the two names of one location right ? Note : My logical understanding of the concepts may be wildly wrong, so do clarify any concepts if you can. Thank You.

Comment: @ThomasAMathew All is written in my answer.

Comment: Ok Vlad. Thanks for your help.